multiple pattern matching on iteration
val subjectpairs = IndexedSeq((8,0),(3,4),(0,9),(6,1))
val priors =  subjectpairs.map { case( f,_) => f}.filter{ _ >0.0}
val posts =  subjectpairs.map { case( _,l) => l}.filter{ _ >0.0}

This creates 2 sequences from the first , with the first and second members of tuples as non-zero respectively.
However , this needs 2 iterations of the source sequence - which is quite inefficient.
Any suggestion on achieving this with a single iteration ( + any other improvement)  - given that the sequence itself will be non-trivial.

Take a look to partitionMap You can also just do your own foldLeft

Just use mutable ListBuffers. As long as they don't escape the scope of your helper function, there is nothing wrong with using fast mutable buffers and good ol' for-loops and if-elses.
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer 
 
def unzipAndFilter[A, B](input: List[(A, B)])(pA: A => Boolean)(pB: B => Boolean): (List[A], List[B]) = {
  val aBldr = new ListBuffer[A]
  val bBldr = new ListBuffer[B]
  for (a, b) <- input do
    if (pA(a)) aBldr += a
    if (pB(b)) bBldr += b
  (aBldr.result, bBldr.result)
}

Usage:
unzipAndFilter(List((8,0),(3,4),(0,9),(6,1)))(_ > 0)(_ > 0)

// (List(8, 3, 6),List(4, 9, 1))

Or with Scala 3 extension syntax:
extension [A, B](input: List[(A, B)])
  def unzipAndFilter[A, B](pA: A => Boolean)(pB: B => Boolean): (List[A], List[B]) = {
    val aBldr = new ListBuffer[A]
    val bBldr = new ListBuffer[B]
    for (a, b) <- input do
      if (pA(a)) aBldr += a
      if (pB(b)) bBldr += b
    (aBldr.result, bBldr.result)
  }

and then
input.unzipAndFilter(_ > 0)(_ > 0)

There seems to be no unzipCollect in the standard library, unfortunately.
